# configuring  Subversion in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ipad, svn

I have configured SVN repositories in my XCode,I have imported and checked out well.but how can i commit and revert files which are in xCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XCode 4.x:**

- *File / Source Control / Commit* to get a list of all changed files to commit.
- For one file go to navigator, right click and select *Source Control*. There you'll find commit, revert, etc.

**XCode 3.26:**

- Menu SCM *Commit Entire Project*
- Current file: *Commit Changes* or *Discard Changes* but this is only available when your editor pane is split and the file is selected in the list of (changed) files
  [image]

Comment: hey, i am using xcode 3.2.6 .i could not see source control under file menu..pls help?

Comment: where can i see     Menu SCM Commit Entire Project
    Current file: Commit Changes or Discard Changes

Comment: Again, see updated answer. If you don't see the SCM menu this indicates that your project is not configured properly for using SVN. Check Project / Settings - SCM or the button Configure Roots & SCM